# How to properly use modf

Tags: c

I'm trying to use modf function but it does not work properly, it does not sign integral part to the variable

```
float intp;
float fracp;
float x = 3.14;
fracp = modf(x,&intp);
printf("%f %f\n", intp,fracp);
```

will give me `0.00000 0.14000`
what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: -1 for apparently not taking *any* advantage of compiler warnings.

Comment: -1 for not reading the man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `&intp` (a `float *`) to a parameter requiring a `double *`.  That causes undefined behaviour.  You need to use `modff`:

```
fracp = modff(x,&intp);
```

or make `intp` a `double` instead:

```
double intp;
```

And you'll be fine.

You should turn on more warnings in your compiler.  For example, even with no special flags, clang gives:

```
example.c:9:20: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'float *' to
      parameter of type 'double *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    fracp = modf(x,&intp);
                   ^~~~~
/usr/include/math.h:400:36: note: passing argument to parameter here
extern double modf(double, double *);
                                   ^
1 warning generated.
```

For your program.

Check out the [`modf` and `modff` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/modf/) to see where you went wrong.